# iad failure ios6

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios6, admob, iad

I have made ​​my application in cocos2d, and has added advertising iad and admob, but to upgrade to ios6, when I click on the ad, then returning to the application and amending view is vertical, completely distorting the game, putting the wrong image.
What's going on? What have they done with ios6 to stop working so much? 'And finally as you can fix that?

Comment: Can you show us some code showing how you're displaying the ad, as well as how you're handling orientation changes in your app? What version of cosos2d are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Me also had same problem in iOS6, cocos2D game with admob. Finally we fixed this issue by using new admob sdk from admob site.

Hereis new iOS6 [admob sdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadios).

Comment: Sorry friend, I've tried to add the new AdMob SDK and got it.
It only happens in admob, but in iad.
In the iOS 5 works great, and when you click on the advertising on iOS5 simulator rotates to portrait view, but in the ios6 not rotate the simulator and when he returns to the game, the screen if it is turned, I added the ADsupported.framework but then nothing works in iOS5 and ios6 remains the same. I suppose it's for something missing in the code but I can not find it